# Can a nested function have undefined parameters valued outside the scope?

Tags: javascript, math

The nested function parameter number is undefined correct?

```
function multiplier(factor) {
  return function(number) {
    return number * factor;
  };
}

var twice = multiplier(2);
console.log(twice(5));
```

Comment: It will only be undefined if you use `twice()` or `twice(undefined)`. But if you use `twice(5)`, then `number` will be `5`.

Comment: I don't really understand your Q, but what happens here is that `multiplier` returns a function, (at that stage `number` hasn't been defined yet) when twice is called number gets the paramater

Answer (score 1):

> The nested function parameter number is undefined correct?

No.

You call `multiplier` which returns a function that expects one argument (named `number`). You assign that function to `twice`.

Then you call `twice` and you pass an argument to `number`.

Comment: number is twice, so twice is 2 and factor is 5?

Comment: No. `number` is `5`, `twice` is a function, `factor` is `2`.

Comment: so basically 5 is automatically assigned to the undefined parameter which is number?

Comment: `5` is assigned to `number` in exactly the same way as any other regular function call. You put `5` between the `(` and the `)` when you called `twice` so the first argument to `twice` is `5` and you defined that argument as being named `number` when you created the function in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Unless your defining "number" somewhere else in your code yes it would be undefined or in the case of twice it would be 5.

Comment: That's not true. `number` here is valuated as a local variable, if you don't pass a parameter it will be `undefined`. The fact that you have a global `number` variable doesn't affect the result.

Comment: Can someone explain this in dummy rhetoric, is it because of the flow. Okay so since its not logged to the console, the factor is two and the number parameter is 5, so is t a matter of flow control.

Comment: @Vohuman Im speaking of the case where "number" would be defined as a variable. as in calling console.log(number) would return undefined. as I said, when he passes 5 to number in the twice function call, it has a value of 5.